# button click in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to test an image button click in Selenium.

The image is the event, when I click the sgt message appears me

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="jcrm-botondetalle">
    <a href="https://www.example.dsa.eu/ConsultaExample/">
       <img src="./../../img/entrar.png" class="jcrm-img1">
    </a>
</div>


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import time
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
try:
    import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter    
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter    
import pytesseract

def evert_init():
    BaseUrl = "https://www.example.dsa.eu/"
    UrlDirection= BaseUrl + "seccion/servicios/detalles/0/c3.html"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/developer/lear-seleniun/chromedriver')  
    driver.get(UrlDirection)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("jcrm-img1")

evert_init()
```

Comment: Please, expose what is good and what is wrong. When reading your message all seem OK. Read again [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the class method, it is working for me

```
submit=driver.find_element_by_class_name("jcrm-img1")
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("jcrm-img1").click()`

Should send a click event to element returned by that selector.